# Change selection color of whole page

Tags: css, selection

I'm currently using

```
::selection {
background: rgba(3, 35, 75, .7);
}
```

But that only changes the color/opacity when I've selected a text or something. It goes to the default color/opacity on blank spaces etc when I press CTRL+A.

How do I change this?

Example:
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlYQM.png)
Note that the gray selection is blue, it just acts as I've tabbed out.

Comment: This is because `::selection` only applies for the dom-elements itself and not for margins or empty space.

Comment: @nicael it seems to work fine there. But if you check the site I'm currently working on www.angryviking.teamcowgames.net you see that some areas are set to default blue. Not sure why

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel how do I make it apply to every element?

Comment: Hm yes, it does indeed look wrong on your site.

Comment: @Condolent If there is nothing to be selected, it cannot be selected.

Comment: Your question is not clear, What do you want? Every element should look like selected? What to do want when `ctrl+A` is pressed? Empty spaces should also be selected?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is good practice, but it will work with `*` selector.

```
*::selection {
background: rgba(3, 35, 75, .7);
}
```

Comment: This will do exactly the same as the OP's selector - the result will be no different.

Answer (score -4):

try replacing all the numbers, the last one is the important one to replace.

Comment: well that only sets the opacity. I want it to have 70% opacity

Comment: Please provide code with your answer - this is not an answer.